# multiple asynchronous callbacks javascript how do I resolve this?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I got myself into a tangle which probably involves multiple asynchronous callback situations.

I have a javascript function called populatePageArea()

Inside populatePageArea it traverses through this array-like variable called pages amongst other code.

```
function populatePagesArea() {
  // there was some code before the for loop

  for (var i=0, l=pages.length; i<l; i++) {    
    addToPagesArea(pages[i], "");   
  }

  // some code after...
}
```

Inside addToPagesArea function, I used the FileAPI from HTML 5 to preview the drag'n dropped files amongst other code.

```
function addToPages(file, front) {
  // there was some code before..
  reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function (theDiv) {
    return function (evt) {
      var backgroundimage = "url(" + evt.target.result + ")";
  theDiv.css("background-image", backgroundimage);
      var sizeSettings = getSizeSettingsFromPage(file, calculateRatio);

};

  }(imageDiv));

  // step#3 execute file reader
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  // there was some code after..
}
```

So every time I previewed the file, I also attempted to do some calculation on the dimensions of the file.

```
function getSizeSettingsFromPage(file, whenReady) {
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function(evt) {
            var width = this.width;
            var height = this.height;
            var filename = file.name;
            if (whenReady) {
                whenReady(width, height, filename);
            }
        };
        image.src = evt.target.result; 
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}
 function calculateRatio(width, height, filename) {

    var ratio = width/height;

    var object = new Object();
    object['height']    = width;
    object['width']     = height;
    object['ratio']     = ratio;
    object['size']      = 'Original';

    for (var size in SIZES) {
        var min = SIZES[size].ratio - 0.01;
        var max = SIZES[size].ratio + 0.01;

        if (ratio <= max && ratio >= min) {
            object['size'] = size;
        }
    }

    pageSizes.add(filename, object);

}
```

**pageSizes** as seen in calculateRatio is a global variable which is an array-like type of variable.

It is definitely empty BEFORE populatePagesArea gets called.

Here is the situation:

my code is:

```
populatePagesArea();
getMajorityPageSize(); // this acts on the supposedly non-empty pageSizes global variable
```

But because I think the calculateRatio has not been called on ALL the previewed images, the pageSizes is always empty when getMajorityPageSize is called.

**how can i make sure that after populatePagesArea is called, getMajorityPageSize gets triggered ONLY after all the `pages` have undergone calculateRatio function?**

I believe this is asynchronous callback. But I am not sure how to do it for an array of objects that will need to undergo an async callback function like calculateRatio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution (I have marked my changes with `// ***`:

```
// ***
var totalPages;

function populatePagesArea() {
  // there was some code before the for loop

  // ***
  totalPages = pages.length;
  for (var i=0, l=pages.length; i<l; i++) {    
    addToPagesArea(pages[i], "");   
  }

  // some code after...
}

function addToPages(file, front) {
    // there was some code before..
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function (theDiv) {
      return function (evt) {
        var backgroundimage = "url(" + evt.target.result + ")";
        theDiv.css("background-image", backgroundimage);
        var sizeSettings = getSizeSettingsFromPage(file, calculateRatio);
        // *** Check to see if we're done after every load
        checkPagesReady();
      };

    }(imageDiv));

    // step#3 execute file reader
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    // there was some code after..
}

// *** Call getMajorityPageSize() here, only after all pages have loaded.
function checkPagesReady() {
    if (pageSizes.length >= totalPages)
        getMajorityPageSize();
}
```

---

The better solution if you're going to be dealing with more asynchronous things later on would be to refactor your code using [promises](https://www.google.com/#q=promises+javascript). Promises is an API designed for dealing with asynchronous programming in a systematic and organized way. It'll make your life a lot easier if you're going to be doing more async work. There's a lot of free libraries that support promises, one of the major players is [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

Comment: Hi Nathan, thank you! i only made one change to your code. I moved the calling of checkpagesready to the last line of calculateRatio.

Comment: by the way, i came across this https://github.com/caolan/async#series  compared with promises, which one is er.. more promising? Heh, pun intended.

Comment: If you're going to be working a lot with Node, the Async library you linked to may be pretty helpful because it follows Node conventions more closely. However, I think promises are a more robust and powerful solution, and there have been some efforts to move Node in that direction as well. In addition, there are a lot of discussions about [adding promises to a future version of ECMAScript](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:concurrency). So I definitely think they are worth learning.

Comment: I saw the Pyramid of Doom described in Q.js README on github. I am already sold on it. I have several such Pyramids in my code right now! Thanks for the suggestion, Nathan!

Comment: Hi Nathan, I took your advice and tried to refactor using Promises. However, having read the documentation, i am still not too sure how to go about refactoring. I have distilled the most essential parts into a github repo and into this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597909/how-to-use-q-js-promises-to-work-with-multiple-asynchronous-operations Hope that you can give me some pointers.